# My website mobile view displays hidden elements properly on desktop when I resize screen to mobile but on my phone they are not hidden

Tags: css, mobile

So i have this code in my css file to hide certain items from my topbar in my website and when i view the site on my desktop and inspect with mobile view the items I want hidden are correctly hidden but when I go to the website on my phone the items are visible.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #topbar {
    height: 50vh;   
  }
  #topbar img {
    max-height: 90px;
  }
 #topbar .social-links a {
    display:none;
  }
  #topbar .logo {
    display:flex;
    align-content:space-evenly;
  }
  #topbar i {
    display:none;
  }
  #topbar a {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I hope you try again after clean phone browser cache.

Comment: Haha didnt think of that, that worked! @WangYinXing

Answer (score 0):

I hope you try again after clean phone browser cache.

Thank you.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try clean browser cache.
It maybe browser issue.